# Submenu item displayed ontop of eachother

Tags: css

Hello there I have a little question with my little problem...

I'm trying to code a submenu to display in a list, but it keeps on showing child items one behind the previous one.

Main menu is a horizontal one and I would like to display the menu vertically. Where is the problem?

The HTML was generated by Joomla CMS, and the CSS is from an external Template I need to modify for a dropdown menu.

```
<ul class="nav menuli" id="mainlevel-nav">
    <li class="item-435 current active">
       <a href="/">Home</a></li><li class="item-497 deeper parent">
       <a href="/index.php/versicherung">Versicherung</a>
           <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
           <li class="item-498"><a class="mainlevel-menu" href="/index.php/versicherung/kfz-versicherung">KFZ-Versicherung</a></li>
           <li class="item-499"><a href="/index.php/versicherung/haftpflichtversicherung">Haftpflichtversicherung</a></li>
           <li class="item-500"><a href="/index.php/versicherung/unfallversicherung">Unfallversicherung</a></li>
           <li class="item-501"><a href="/index.php/versicherung/rechtsschutzversicherung">Rechtsschutzversicherung</a></li>
           <li class="item-502"><a href="/index.php/versicherung/haus-und-wohnen">Haus und Wohnen</a></li></ul</li>
      <li class="item-472"><a href="/index.php/finanzierung" title="Finanzierung">Finanzierung</a></li>
      <li class="item-496"><a href="/index.php/veranlagung">Veranlagung</a></li>
      <li class="item-473"><a href="/index.php/kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
      <li class="item-495"><a href="/index.php/impressum">Impressum</a></li>
      <li class="item-494"><a href="/index.php/news">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
ul#mainlevel-menu{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    background: none
}

ul#mainlevel-menu li{
    display:inline;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 32px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:relative;
}

ul#mainlevel-menu li a{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: transparent;
}

ul#mainlevel-menu li a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Menu Sub */

ul#mainlevel-nav li li{
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:20%;
    background-image:url('../images/menu_bg.jpg')
    }

ul#mainlevel-nav li:hover ul li{display:block}

/* End Menu */
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you minimize it to only include the relevent part? Or make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BRre6/

Comment: Forgot to tell you, that the problem is in the Versicherung parent, when you hover on it the submenu should show in an list order one after another with list-style:none. But it just cramps them ontop of eachother.

Comment: Your CSS code is full of errors. And CSS code without the associated HTML code makes no sense! So please post the relevant part of your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres your Html

```
    <head>
  <base href="http://johann2.hard-worx.eu/">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Super User">
  <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link href="http://johann2.hard-worx.eu/" rel="canonical">
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('load', function() {
                new JCaption('img.caption');
            });
  </script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/_system/css/general.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/wm_07_31/css/template.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>


<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="top">

        <div id="logo"> <a href="/index.php"><img src="/templates/wm_07_31/images/logo.png" alt="
Notice: Undefined variable: siteName in /var/www/vhosts/hard-worx.eu/subdomains/johann2/httpdocs/templates/wm_07_31/index.php on line 22
" title="
Notice: Undefined variable: siteName in /var/www/vhosts/hard-worx.eu/subdomains/johann2/httpdocs/templates/wm_07_31/index.php on line 22
"></a>
        </div>

<div id="mainmenu">
                    <ul class="nav menuli" id="mainlevel-nav">
<li class="item-435 current active"><a href="/">Home</a></li><li class="item-497 deeper parent"><a href="/index.php/versicherung">Versicherung</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small ultestClass"><li class="item-498 testClassLi"><a class="mainlevel-menu" href="/index.php/versicherung/kfz-versicherung">KFZ-Versicherung</a></li><li class="item-499 testClassLi"><a href="/index.php/versicherung/haftpflichtversicherung">Haftpflichtversicherung</a></li><li class="item-500 testClassLi"><a href="/index.php/versicherung/unfallversicherung">Unfallversicherung</a></li><li class="item-501 testClassLi"><a href="/index.php/versicherung/rechtsschutzversicherung">Rechtsschutzversicherung</a></li><li class="item-502 testClassLi"><a href="/index.php/versicherung/haus-und-wohnen">Haus und Wohnen</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-472"><a href="/index.php/finanzierung" title="Finanzierung">Finanzierung</a></li><li class="item-496"><a href="/index.php/veranlagung">Veranlagung</a></li><li class="item-473"><a href="/index.php/kontakt">Kontakt</a></li><li class="item-495"><a href="/index.php/impressum">Impressum</a></li><li class="item-494"><a href="/index.php/news">News</a></li></ul>

        </div>

        <div id="maincontent">

      <div id="left">

        </div>

        <div id="content"> 

            <div class="item-page">



                                <h2 class="componentheading">Home</h2>
<p><strong>Willkommen beim Versicherungsmaklerbüro Germadnik KG</strong></p>
<p><strong><br></strong>Das Versicherungsmaklerbüro Ihres Vertrauens.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h1>Wir liefernd Ihnen maßgeschneiderte Lösungen</h1>
<ul style="list-style-type: disc;">
<li>Versicherung</li>
<li>Finanzierung</li>
<li>Veranlagung</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td>
<h1>TOP Kooperationen in den Bereichen</h1>
<ul style="list-style-type: disc;">
<li>Versicherungen</li>
<li>Finanzierungen</li>
<li>Vermögen</li>
<li>Bausparen</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

                         </div>

        </div>
        </div>

    </div>



    <div id="footer">   
        <div id="footer_top"></div>
            <div id="footer_bg">
            <div id="footer_content">
                </div>
        <div id="footer_bot"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="copyright"><a href="http://www.blitz-it.at/" title="Blitz-IT.at">Design Blitz-it.at</a> <br>

    </div>

</div>







</div></body>
```

And here is your css file

```
   body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #999999;
    background-image: url('../images/bg.gif');
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #626262;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 928px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}


#logo {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
}

#topmenu {
    float:left;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.frontimage {
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

/* Menu */
#mainmenu {
    clear: both;
    width: 900px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url('../images/menu_bg.jpg');
    margin-left:14px;
}

/* top navigation */
ul#mainlevel-nav{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    background: none
}

ul#mainlevel-nav li{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 1px solid #666666;
    background: none
}

ul#mainlevel-nav li a{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: transparent;
}

ul#mainlevel-nav li a:hover{
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* for mainmenu flat list on the blue bg */
ul#mainlevel-menu{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    background: none
}

ul#mainlevel-menu li{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 32px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul#mainlevel-menu li a{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: transparent;
}

ul#mainlevel-menu li a:mouseenter{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*TEST*/

ul#mainlevel-nav li{
    border-radius: 5%;
    list-style: none;
    display:block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    position:relative;

}

ul#mainlevel-nav li li{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    float: top;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
    background: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url('../images/menu_bg.jpg');
    background-color: #424921;
    position: absolute; 
    top:inherit;
    top:inherit;
    left:0;
    margin: 0px;
}

ul#mainlevel-nav li li a{
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
    background: none;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    border: 10px;

}

ul#mainlevel-nav li a:hover{
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#mainlevel-nav li li {display:none}
#mainlevel-nav li:hover > ul li{
    display:block;
    }



/* End Topmenu */


/* Content */

#maincontent {
}

div#content {
    width:666px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:14px;
    margin-top:14px;
    margin-bottom:14px;
}



/* Menu Sub */




/* End Menu */

#left {
    width:220px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:14px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}


.clr{
    clear:both
}

/*Make round left modules */

div.module_menu div, div.module div {
    background-image: url(../images/box_bg.gif);
}

div.module_menu div div, div.module div div{
    background-image: url(../images/box_top.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}

div.module_menu div div div, div.module div div div{
    background-image: url(../images/box_bot.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

/* End round left modules */


.module_menu h3, .module_menu h3, .module h3    {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.module_menu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

.module ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin:0;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.module li {
}

.module li a {
    font-size:11px;
    color:#ce2027;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.module_menu li {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    border-bottom-color: #333;
}
.module_menu li:hover {
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

.module_menu li li {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.module_menu li li:last-child {
    border:none;
}


.module_menu li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
    line-height:24px;
    padding:5px;

}
.moduletable{


}

div.module_menu, div.module {
    margin-top:14px;
}


.module p {
    font-size:10px;
}

/*module_menu*/

fieldset {
    border:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

input.inputbox {
    width:188px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

input.button {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

input#modlgn_remember {
    width:10px;
    border:none;
}


/* Main CSS */

img {
    border:none;
}

.contentheading, h1 {
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

p {
    line-height: 18px;
}

a { 
    color: #626262;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.modifydate, .createdate, .small {
    font-size:9px;
    color:#b8151c;
}

.componentheading {
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#b8151c;
    background-image: url(../images/contentp_line.gif);
    background-position: right bottom;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.componentheading a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #626262;
    background-image: url(../images/spacer.gif);
}

#footer {
    clear:both;
    margin-left:14px;

}
#footer_top {
    background-image: url(../images/footer_top.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    height:10px;
    width:900px;
    clear:both;
}


#footer_bot{
    background-image: url(../images/footer_bot.jpg);
    height:10px;
    width:900px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
}

#footer_content {
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    background-image: url(../images/footer_bg.jpg);
    clear:both;
    margin-left:-14px;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: top;
}
#spacer {
    width: 928px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:14px;
    clear:both;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#copyright {
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:9px;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:18px;
}

#webmedie {
    font-size:9px;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:18px;
}
.ultestClass{
    width:0%;
    position : absolute;
}
.testClassLi{
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Let me know if this doesnot work

Comment: Will check it out when I get home. The only problem is I have no access to HTML Code. I can juat esit the css and index of the template. Then I have to install the template to Joomla site. I hope your aolution lies within the css. If not I'm screwed:)

Comment: Give a try copy pasting in the jsfiddle. Btw good news yes  only css issue nothing else :) Added some class and their style. Your not screwed. :)

Comment: Holly BANANAS:) U did it again:) IF it's possible could you PM me a small walkthrough what was wrong and how you repaired the bloody madness and what do your changes do? Ummm. Just a little edit: it worked on jfiddle but on the site the changes aren't applied. What went wrong?

Comment: First accept it :) Kidding . Actually the ul took a horizontal alignment so i provided the width of the ul and also marked it as absolute as it needed to be independent or else other divs would have been pushed here and there :)

Comment: Can't make it work. Why? Can you be so kind and highlight the changes you have made? I have to be blind or bloody dumb not to get it to work.

Comment: last two styles .ultestClass{
    width:0%;
    position : absolute;
}
.testClassLi{
    position: relative !important;
} and added their respective class to the ul and li respectively

Comment: is it not working it was working on fiddle. If any online website link you can post it

Comment: Ok found your changes :) DUH. Since I can't access my HTML, must I declare all of the child items? With your .testClassLi it works. As soon I try to use item-xxx class it gives me a kick in the head.

Comment: Hey I think I got it:) It works as you described. Only question remains now: Do I have to declare every submenu item with your .testCLassLi code or is there a workaround? EDIT: With what can I align the submenu item with it's parent item?

Comment: yes the li should have that class else how can one apply stiling may be using childnodes . use .unstyled > li guess that should work

Comment: Sorry this wont help ... need to some how insert at least a class to ul .

Comment: Kick my dumb arse and call me Charlie! Anobik you just made my day much much better. When did you learn all this? You surely deserver a raise and a case of Puntigamer (BEER)! I used left: for positioning by the way.

Comment: I dont know y but u look in excited state :P :P Thanks :) happy to help.

Comment: please accept it :( After having such long discussion it seems so odd to me that it is not accepted :P

Comment: I'll tell you why: it's been bothering me for 2 bloody day. I search the whole web for an anwser but to no prevail. With your help the problem is finally solved. I accepted your anwser, kind sire. Sorry about that:) I'm still a rookie on this site:) EDIT: Just one more quick thing: how to make the submenu to always display under the parent no matter what screen size I'm using?

Comment: youll learn :) One strange fact I don't drink so beer offer in vain :D :D keep Posting questions lot of people are there to help :) Including me

Comment: Just one more quick thing: how to make the submenu to always display under the parent no matter what screen size I'm using? U don't drink beer? Damn, than I'll have to ask my wife to drink it for you-> 2 beers for me and I'm on a rollercoaster:)

Comment: It depends upon the position attribute in css. Always use inspect element or firebug . There might be various conditions that menu might not appear so u always need to debug it using firebug. Actually there are several methods for different scenario:) I just think on the fly so cannot give a particular one righ now

Comment: Ok got your point. Now how do I do itso that the position will be dependant on the wrapper I have? EDIT: Because I got it by that all the positioning is based on the screen. How to implement the positioning to depend on the declared wrapper?